# Please help for sum with condition in impala

Tags: impala

Today I need somebody help for this questions.
My data

```
--------|-------------|------------|------------
           PPP             BBB         BBBs
acno111   160716463.59  2327181.57   14825211.29
cno           0             0           0
cny           0             0           0
usd        313489.30    1257613.04  1257613.04 
swd           0         1069568.53           0
thb        14825211.29      0        12
```

question :
If it is in another currency, select the PPP column.
Of the same line, for example USD is 313489.30
  But in THB
Use the same line, PPP column 14825211.29 minus
Column, BBB, the top combination is the total amount 2327181.57
Equals 14825211.29 - 2327181.57 = 12498029.72

Please help resolve the problem.

Comment: Requirement is little confusing but here is what i am thinking...  select PPP-max_BBB as out_val
FROM my_table
JOIN (select MAX(BBB) as max_BBB from my_table)
WHERE col1='thb'

Comment: In other words, for example 111, if it's in another currency, sum up at the same row.
But if in baht Must take the same total line, minus the total